# Suddenly getting "syntaxerror: Unexpected Token" in PUG CLI

Tags: pug

I've been working on a project in PUG, but with one of my last changes to the code, I'm now getting Syntaxerror: unexpected token" from the PUG CLI parser. Here's the relevant bit of code:

```
mixin hexagonLabelContainer(divClass,transKey,transValue,locked,buttonDetails)
    div(class=`hexagon-label-container${divClass ? ` ${divClass}` : ''}`)
        +trueHexagon(locked)
            block
        if !buttonDetails
            span(class='hexagon-label' data-i18n=transKey)
                != transValue||transKey;
        else
            button&attributes(buttonDetails)
                != buttonDetails.content || '';
```

and the exact error text:

```
Error: puggenefunk2090.pug:27:28
    25|                 if !buttonDetails
    26|                         span(class='hexagon-label' data-i18n=transKey)
  > 27|                                 != transValue||transKey;
-----------------------------------^
    28|                 else
    29|                         button&attributes(buttonDetails)
    30|                                 != buttonDetails.content || '';

Syntax Error: Unexpected token
FILE PATH INFO REDACTED
```

It's something with the code reference, cause if I replace `!= transvalue||transKey` with any pure text content for the span (e.g. `|random text`) it parses that line correctly, and then just throws the error on the next line where I'm using unescaped code. This continues down the code for as far as I've bothered to track it.

I've even taken this down to a minimum replicable state, which is literally just a code call:

```
!= `random text done as a string for no good reason`;
```

But, I can't see any typos on my part. So, what glaringly obvious typo have I made here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the semicolons. [Unescaped buffered code](https://pugjs.org/language/code.html#unescaped-buffered-code) lines in Pug shouldn't be terminated with semicolons. A quick test using the Pug compiler in [CodePen](https://codepen.io/) can confirm this.

Removing the semicolons from your mixin should fix the issue:

```
mixin hexagonLabelContainer(divClass,transKey,transValue,locked,buttonDetails)
  div(class=`hexagon-label-container${divClass ? ` ${divClass}` : ''}`)
    +trueHexagon(locked)
      block
    if !buttonDetails
      span(class='hexagon-label' data-i18n=transKey)
        != transValue||transKey
    else
      button&attributes(buttonDetails)
        != buttonDetails.content || ''
```

Similarly, your minimum example should be written as:

```
!= `random text done as a string for no good reason`
```

Comment: Thank you! I knew it had to be something simple I'd screwed up